# Не могу сделать Scroolspy

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так я делаю для `scrollspy`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
(function($){
var sections = [];

$('#mainnav li a').each(function() {
sections.push($(this).attr('href'));
});

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() );
for(var i in sections) {
    var section = sections[i];
}
})

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/e2fcnn ccылка на меню к вопросу!)

Comment: Напишите ваше меню кодом, как это вы сделали с кодом на javascript. А также опишите словами проблему, что происходит, и что должно происходить?